# Folder Monitoring with C#

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a question regarding the viability of using FileSystemWatcher in my particular application.  What I have is an application that monitors folder creation for a lab test machine.  The machine processes vials of mash to determine how much alcohol exists in them. When the machine completes its analysis it produces a report which it saves to a hard drive location.  Within the folder that the machine creates are two files which I read with my current process and write the values to database tables.

My current process however has high overhead and basically re-reads the directory which stores the test folders each time it runs.  Over time the folder will become so large that the reading process will probably consume the resources on the computer.

So I am thinking about changing the code to use FileSystemWatcher, but it has been suggested before that when many files are created in the path that watcher is watching those files can be missed. When a folder is created by the lab system it creates about 136 files in that folder.

Will this work for monitoring when I am only interested in two CSV files inside that folder?

Comment: Reading one big block of text is almost impossible. Do you have a specific question? At the very least use separate paragraphs

Comment: `"Will this work...?"` it will, if you take care to not block the FSW events by trying to do all the processing in the event handler. If you use queueing, dataflow blocks or Channel to offload processing to another thread you won't have any problems